# unable to cast object of type 'system.windows.forms.bindingsource' to type 'system.data.datatable'

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-core

I'm experiencing the following exception

> unable to cast object of type 'system.windows.forms.bindingsource' to type 'system.data.datatable'

Here is my method

```
private void GridViewStudentsList_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    try {
        BindingSource bindingSource = (BindingSource) GridViewStudentsList.DataSource;
        DataTable changes = (DataTable) bindingSource.DataSource;
        changes.GetChanges();
        if (changes != null) {
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connection);
            con.Open();
            OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
            OracleCommandBuilder mcb = new OracleCommandBuilder(adapter);
            adapter.UpdateCommand = mcb.GetUpdateCommand();
            adapter.Update(changes);
            changes.AcceptChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Cell Updated");
            con.Close();
            return;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: So have you tried to debug it and peeked what type `bindingSource.DataSource` is?

Comment: bindingSource.DataSource = 'bindingSource.DataSource' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Comment: bindingSource.DataSource = {College_Management_System.ViewStudentData}

Comment: now i have changed DataTable to DataSet now it works but again it displays an error\"Operation is not valid due to current state of the object"

Comment: The new exception is thrown at which line?

Comment: in this line : adapter.UpdateCommand = mcb.GetUpdateCommand();

Answer (score 0):

> I have done some minor mistakes

#### Below Code is working code

```
    private void GridViewStudentsList_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
  
 {


        try
       
          {
            
            BindingSource bindingSource = (BindingSource)GridViewStudentsList.DataSource;

            DataSet changes = (DataSet)bindingSource.DataSource;

            changes.GetChanges();

            if (changes != null)
            {
                OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connection);
                con.Open();
                OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter("select * from students_list",con );
                GridViewStudentsList.EndEdit();
               OracleCommandBuilder mcb = new OracleCommandBuilder(adapter);
           
                adapter.UpdateCommand = mcb.GetUpdateCommand(true);
              
         
                adapter.Update(changes,"students_list");
               changes.AcceptChanges();

                MessageBox.Show("Cell Updated");
               // GridViewStudentsList.EndEdit();
                con.Close();
                return;
            }


        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```